# Button Icon Change on Click

Tags: qt, button, user-interface, pyside, python-3.3

I'm trying to make a GUI Application that change the icon on the right clicked button!
This is my simple code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.buttons = list()

        for x in range(3):
            row = list()
            for y in range(3):
                button = QPushButton(QIcon('Empty-Cell.png'), '{},{}'.format(x, y))
                button.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
                row.append(button)
                layout.addWidget(button, x, y)
            self.buttons.append(row)

        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def button_click(self):
        # Change icon HERE!

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and here the image:

[Link of the GUI Application](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/834/kaqc.png)

I've been trying for hours but i'm not still able to do that, any ideas?
I would like also to use an Image Widget instead of a button, label, or whatelse if it is possible..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QObject::sender` to get the clicked button.

```
def button_click(self):
    test_pixmap = QPixmap(16, 16)
    test_pixmap.fill(Qt.red)
    self.sender().setIcon(QIcon(test_pixmap))
```

Comment: Well, it works! Is there any way to make a widget image clickable, instead using a button?

Comment: What do you mean by widget image? You can get click events of any widget (e.g. a `QLabel` that can display pixmaps) by installing an event filter on it. I.e. call `self.label.installEventFilter(self)` and implement `eventFilter` method of your main window class.